# Setting user's uid as the document's identifier in my users collection in cloud firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am creating a sign up module in react native expo where I am using firebase's email/password authentication. To store the additional signup fields, I am using cloud firestore as my database.

Now inside my users collection, I want to add each record by having the **uid inside the record as the document's title** for facilitated lookups later.

```
try {
      const userCredential = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
      const user = userCredential.user;
  
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(user));

      try {
        const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "users", user.uid), {
          email: email,
          username: username,
          phonenumber: phonenumber,
          uid: user.uid,
          isAdmin: false,
          isSeller: false,
          sellerID: null,
          chats: [],
        });
        console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
      } catch (e) {
        console.error("Error adding document: ", e);
      }
```

So i tried adding my user document like above in my users collection but firebase throws the following error upon execution.

> ERROR  Error adding document:  [FirebaseError: Invalid collection reference. Collection references must have an odd number of segments, but users/RF1qXof3iIeDN9m28YutGa4486Y2 has 2.]

I was expecting this to set the document's title equal to the uid but instead this error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

`addDoc` creates a new document with a random ID in a named collection.  It looks like you already know that you want a specific ID, so this operation won't work for you.  Use `setDoc` instead, which lets you specify the ID given a DocumentReference that you normally create using `doc()`.

```
await setDoc(doc(db, "users", user.uid), { ... })
```

See the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document) for more information.

Comment: await setDoc(doc(db, "users", user.uid)
This is the exact thing that worked out for me.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, it's customary to upvote and mark helpful answers as accepted, as a way to reward the person who answered.

Comment: Tried doing that, turns out i need 15 reputation for changes to be visible. I already submitted feedback for your answer.